# Quadratic Diophantine Problem in two variables

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have a quick question in regards to solving a quadratic two-variable diophantine problem. The equation is $6x^2 - 2xy + 3y - 17x = 6$. My attempt thus far starts by making y the subject: $$y = \frac{6x^2 - 17x - 6}{2x - 3}$$
After this I state that $2x - 3$ divides $6x^2 - 17x - 6$ and therefore $6x^2 - 17x - 6 \equiv 0$ (mod $2x - 3$).
I've been trying to use $2x - 3 \equiv 0$ (mod $2x - 3$) to somehow get something going but I simply can't work out how to solve this (most likely simple) problem from this point.

I'd greatly appreciate any input on whether this method is the way to go (and hence how to continue), or if there is a "better" approach.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your idea works: $\,\color{#c00}{2x\equiv 3}\,$ so $\,0\equiv 2f = \overbrace{3(\color{#c00}{2x})^2\!-17(\color{#c00}{2x})-12}^{\large 2\,(6\,x^2\ -\ 17\,x\ -\ 6)\quad }\!\equiv -36\equiv -2^2\cdot 9.\,$  Since $\,2x\!-\!3\,$ is odd we can cancel $\,2\,$ so $\,9\equiv 0,\,$ i.e. $\,2x\!-\!3\mid 9,\ $ so $\ 2x\!-\!3 = \pm\, 1,3,9\ $ so $\,x = \ldots$

Comment: What's the reasoning behind the statement $0 \equiv 2f$? I understand pretty much everything from that point, but simply can't quite understand going from $2x \equiv 3$ (mod 2x-3) to $0 \equiv 2f$.

Comment: @Arbit $\ y = f/(2x\!-\!3)\in\Bbb Z\,$ i.e. $\,2x\!-\!3\mid f,\,$ so $\, {\rm mod}\ 2x\!-\!3\!:\ f\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\,2f\equiv 0.\ $ We scale $\,f\,$ by $\,2\,$ to force every power of $\,x\,$ to be a power of $\,\color{#c00}{2x} (\equiv 3),\,$ i.e. so we can replace $\,2x\,$ by $\,3.\ \ $

Comment: Thanks I understood completely from that explanation

Answer (score 0):

$$6x^2-17x-6=3x(2x-3)-4(2x-3)-6-12\equiv-18\pmod{2x-3}$$

$\implies2x-3$ must divide $18$

Also, $2x-3\equiv1\pmod2$ i.e, $2x-3$ is odd

Comment: Yep I understand this logic. Thanks a lot :)